# JQuery: Detect Class of Element that is not X

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say i have an element:

```
<div class="box box-selected flounderfish"> </div>
```

How do i detect the class that is not `box` and `box-selected` ?

I'd like to have a function like this:

```
$(target).classThatIsNot('box box-selected');
```

to return `flounderfish`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no jQuery function, but you can just use string functions

```
var clazz = $(target).attr('class');
var other = $.trim(clazz.replace('box box-selected',  ''))
```

Comment: On a quick note, because we dont know about the order of classes, i extended the snippet to: `$.trim(clazz.replace('box', '').replace('box-selected', ''));`

Comment: @JonJomate `var clazz = "box box-selected other";$.trim(clazz.replace(/box|-selected/gi, "")) // other`

Comment: @JonJomate Without `$.trim()` `var clazz = "box box-selected other"; clazz.replace(/box|-|selected|\s+/gi, "") // "other"` . Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

use the `not` selector

```
$(target).not('.box box-selected');
```

More info on the not selector [here](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

Comment: Uhm.. I think you mixed something up there, `:not()` is a selector, not a method, meaning it would be inside the `$(  )`. And this wouldn't return anything useful.

Comment: The link points to the not-selector, but there is a `not()` method which is an opposite of `filter()` method. See this link: https://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: Wasn't aware of that. As im reading it so far though, it still wouldnt really help in this situation, right?

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
var classes = $(target).attr('class');
var classesArray = classes.split(" ");
```

then you can get every class separately and do what you need.

Comment: True, but the element recieves and loses classes via javascript, so im not sure about their order. You'd have to remove the two known classes and it would be more code to perform.